# asp.net free webcontrol to display crosstab or pivot reports with column and row grouping, subtotals and totals or different approach

Tags: asp.net, report, crosstab, web-controls

I want to develop some crosstab also know as pivot reports in Asp.net with x-axis and y-axis being dynamics, allowing grouping by row and column, for example: have products in y-axis and date in x-axis having in body number of sells of a given product in a given date, if date in x-axis are years, i want subtotals for each month for a product (row) and subtotals of sells of all products in date (column)

I know there are products available to build reports, but i am using Mysql, so Reporting Service is not an option. It's not necessary for the client build additional reports, i think the simplest solution is having a control to display such information and not using crystal report (which is not free) or something more complex, i want to know if is there an available free control to reach my goal.

Well, does anybody know a control or have a different idea, 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want support along with that free control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need SQL Server to run Reporting Services reports.
[gotreportviewer.com](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/) have all the info (look for `Generate RDLC dynamically - Matrix` in the right column)